# Migrating WildFly EAR to GlassFish 7.0.5 + Morphia & MongoDB JARs

Tags: mongodb, glassfish

Trying to deploy an EAR which runs on WildFly 28.0.1 to GlassFish 7.0.5:

```
598 INFO    Realm [admin-realm] successfully updated.(details)  jakarta.enterprise.system.core.security Jun 14, 2023 16:36:18.947   {}
597 SEVERE  ... 12 more(details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.136   {}
596 SEVERE  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolClearedEvent(details)  jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.136   {}
595 SEVERE  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolClearedEvent at com.mongodb.interna... (details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.136   {}
594 SEVERE  Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='6489d7cc0679315bc1560aea', description='null'}-localho... (details)   jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.136   {}
593 SEVERE  ... 12 more(details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.126   {}
592 SEVERE  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolClearedEvent(details)  jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.126   {}
591 SEVERE  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolClearedEvent at com.mongodb.interna... (details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.126   {}
590 SEVERE  Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='6489d7cc0679315bc1560ae9', description='null'}-localho... (details)   jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.126   {}
589 SEVERE  ... 12 more(details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.117   {}
588 SEVERE  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolClearedEvent(details)  jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.116   {}
587 SEVERE  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolClearedEvent at com.mongodb.interna... (details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.116   {}
586 SEVERE  Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='6489d7cc0679315bc1560ae8', description='null'}-localho... (details)   jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.116   {}
585 SEVERE  ... 12 more(details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
584 SEVERE  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolClearedEvent(details)  jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
583 SEVERE  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolClearedEvent at com.mongodb.interna... (details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
582 SEVERE  ... 12 more(details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
581 SEVERE  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)(details) jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
580 SEVERE  at org.glassfish.common.util.GlassfishUrlClassLoader.loadClass(GlassfishUrlClassLoader.java:115)(details)   jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
579 SEVERE  Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='6489d7cc0679315bc1560ae7', description='null'}-localho... (details)   jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
578 SEVERE  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)(details) jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
577 SEVERE  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:674)(details) jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
576 SEVERE  at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:753)(details) jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
575 SEVERE  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.event.ConnectionPoolClearedEvent(details)  jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
574 SEVERE  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolClearedEvent at com.mongodb.interna... (details)    jakarta.enterprise.logging.stderr   Jun 14, 2023 16:08:06.082   {}
573 SEVERE  Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='6489d7cb0679315bc1560ae6', description='null'}-localho... (details)
```

I have MongoDB in my EAR:

```
lib/morphia-core-2.3.0.jar
lib/mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar
lib/mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar
lib/bson-4.9.1.jar
```

On WildFly 28.0.1 it works:

```
INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.client] (default task-1) MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync", "version": "4.9.1"}, "os": {"type": "Darwin", "name": "Mac OS X", "architecture": "x86_64", "version": "13.4"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/20.0.1+9-29"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@2679e193, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@1646d1cd]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
```

Why the error on GlassFish? TIA.

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace of one of the errors? The log you posted contains several error messages, esch of them shows only the first line of the stack trace